# How can I parse specific table data using jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I am developing a small project in which I'm trying to parse updated market prices for the crops from the table on this link:
http://amis.pk/ViewPrices.aspx?searchType=1&commodityId=1

I want to get the output like, Apple(ammre):12500

The code I'm using is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String url="http://amis.pk/ViewPrices.aspx?searchType=1&commodityId=1";
    TextView datatv;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datatv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               new Description().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
        String title;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

Document mBlogDocument = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Log.e("Activity Log", "doInBackground"+mBlogDocument.toString());
Elements table = mBlogDocument.getElementsByClass("table.cart");
Elements tdsInSecondRow = mBlogDocument.select("table tr:nth-child(2) > td");
                 for (Element td : tdsInSecondRow)
                {
                   System.out.println("TD: " + td.text());
                }
s.append(table);
                s.append(tdsInSecondRow);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This code is returning me the complete html of table data in second row but how can i get only the data from 4th column (max price) specific to apple(ammre)? I don't have a clue about that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Without including enough of the page HTML to tell what your code is doing, this question is off-topic. Questions on Stack Overflow must be self contained. That means we need to be able to answer without having to go off-site to get question-specific information (e.g. having to go to a website).

Comment: thanks for adding this information I will keep this in mind . But previous reply helped a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code gets all table rows and prints them one-by-one:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements rows = document.select("#amis_prices").select("tr:not(.labelLists)");
for (Element row : rows) {
    String name = row.select(".listItem").text();
    String maxPrice = row.select(".pricedata:nth-of-type(3)").text();
    System.out.println(name + ": " + maxPrice); // or what is appropriate in your code
}
```

**Please note that if you're coding for android, replace the last line `System.out...` with what is appropeiate to your code - e.g. `button.setText(name + maxPrice)` or...**

If you just want to get the second row, this is how you would do it:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements row = document.select("#amis_prices").select("tr:nth-of-type(2)"); // this 2 means the second row that you wanted
String name = row.select(".listItem").text();
String maxPrice = row.select(".pricedata:nth-of-type(3)").text();
System.out.println(name + ": " + maxPrice); // or what is appropriate in your code
```

Comment: All table headings lies in class ".listItem ". Should this return complete list ? or this isn't working. Clicking button isn't returning any data.

Comment: My code returns all rows like `Apple (Ammre): 12500` then `Apple (Gatcha): -` and so on. Do you need just the second row? And please note that instead of `System.out.println` in last line, do what is appropriate in your android code.

Comment: I need at least ten but individually. like on clicking apple button it returns 'Apple (Ammre) : 12500 ' on another button it returns next one so on . but currently I'm trying to do it with first one . But still your code isn't running. I'm using it as written.

Comment: i can understand this code  completely. Thanks to you.I'm using log.d in android but still it is not printing. I'm trying may be i'm wrong somewhere.